# How do I call FreeMat that was installed via Alien?

Tags: 12.10, 32-bit, alien, freemat

How do I call FreeMat that was installed via Alien? I'm running 12.10 32 bit. I have tried `freemat`, `freemat4.1.1` and `freemat4` and none have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer but looking in the directory `/usr/bin/` for anything that looks like freemat and I found `FreeMat` which means that calling `FreeMat` should call the program.